# Bootstrap grid items not rendering alongside eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with the bootstrap grid system.  The div below `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">` should be on the right side while the other divs are on the left.  Currently the first two column divs are correct and rendering at the top, but then the third column div doesn't render until the bottom of the image rather than alongside it.  I need them to display correctly, what can I do?

```
                  <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                                <h1>WELCOME TO YOUR NETWORK PROGRAM WEBSITE</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <img src="images/tie.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                                <div class="loginText">
                                    Get information about your Connect plan 
                                    <br><br>
                                    If you have any problems logging in, please contact your account manager for help.
                                    <br><br>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- cols -->
                        </div> <!-- row -->
                    </div> <!-- container -->
```

It looks like this [image]

The third div needs to be moved up under the first div, but it's currently below the height of the second div.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's framework is build on a **12 column layout**.

So

`col-md-7` + `col-md-4` + `col-md-7` = 18 columns exceeding the 12 column limit, hence pushing the third div to the next line.

You can fix it by changing the `col-md`'s to `col-md-5` + `col-md-2` + `col-md-5` like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <h1>WELCOME TO YOUR NETWORK PROGRAM WEBSITE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <img src="images/tie.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <div class="loginText">Get information about your Connect plan<br><br>If you have any problems logging in, please contact your account manager for help.<br><br>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- cols -->
</div>
```

Comment: Check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap grid system always adds to 12 in a row. you have md-7 and md-4 that's only 11.

you need to change

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
```

to

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
```

now you have 7+5 =12.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but from what I understand, col-md-7 plus col-md-4 plus col-md-7 equal 18, 6 more than the allotted 12. So it will go onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

So, according to your updated question, you want the text on the left and the image on the right. You can do that as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>WELCOME TO YOUR NETWORK PROGRAM WEBSITE</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- div below is hidden in xs -->
            <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                <div class="loginText">Get information about your Connect plan<br><br>If you have any problems logging in, please contact your account manager for help.<br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <img src="images/tie.png">
    </div>

    <!-- div below is shown only in xs -->
    <div class="col-md-12 visible-xs">
        <div class="loginText">Get information about your Connect plan<br><br>If you have any problems logging in, please contact your account manager for help.<br><br>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you help me by explaining why this works?  Seems like a overly complicated solution, thought there would be a simpler tweak.

Comment: Unless you're ok with the image appearing below the loginText in mobile view, the above is required to make sure the loginText div appears below of the image on mobile. As you must have noticed above, I grouped the text on a separate row spanning 8 columns and the image spanning 4 rows (Desktop).